# How to deploy .NET Core 6 web app to GoDaddy?

Tags: .net-core, deployment, github-actions, plesk

I have a simple .NET Core 6 web app, and I have [GoDaddy's Windows Hosting Deluxe](https://www.godaddy.com/en-au/hosting/windows-hosting) package. It uses Plesk to manage the sites.

[GoDaddy does support .NET Core 6](https://au.godaddy.com/help/windows-plesk-shared-hosting-aspaspnet-module-feature-support-3361)

It appears the only way to get files into Plesk in an automated way is to use FTP. So on github I have this deploy script:

```yaml
name:  Deploy website via FTPS
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
permissions:
  contents: write
jobs:
  web-deploy:
      name:  Deploy
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
      - name:  Get latest code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        
      - name: Setup .NET Core SDK ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: dotnet restore
      - name: Build
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore

      - name:  Upload files via FTPS
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@v4.3.4
        with:
          server: my-real-domain.com
          username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
          local-dir: ./bin/Release/net6.0/
          server-dir: ./
          protocol: ftps
          dangerous-clean-slate: true
          exclude: |
            .cspell.json
            package.json
            package-lock.json
```

That builds everything just fine, and then uploads the contents of `./bin/Release/net6.0/` to my instance of Plesk on GoDaddy.

But, I just get a big red "**403 - Forbidden: Access is denied**" error on my site. What am I doing wrong here? Am I uploading the wrong files, or is there something else entirely that I'm missing?

Comment: I finally managed CD with .NET using an `app_offline.htm`. [Instructions](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/ci-cd-an-asp-net-core-application-to-plesk-azure-996a66450fba). I used a post-deploy script because I assumed git deploy would suspend the application pool. But that's not the case. I guess you may as well just create and delete the `app_offline.htm` through FTP.

Comment: Cool, glad this can be workable. Looking though that link though it uses the "git" section of Plesk, which apparently is not available via GoDaddy's version of Plesk!  I'll be moving off of GoDaddy when I can, it's just not urgent right now

Comment: Ah yes, it depends on what Plesk modules are installed on the server. But I think you can just create the `app_offline.htm` through FTP and delete it afterwards. Just don't forget the delays inbetween. They're really important in order to release the lock on the exe and dll files. However I think 500ms would do also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but this was a fairly simple fix someone might run into in the future.

I needed to run `dotnet publish` instead of `dotnet build`!

Then I just need to upload the contents of the `./bin/Release/net6.0/publish/` folder.

It works now.  Here's my working deploy script

````yaml
```yaml
name:  Deploy website via FTPS
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
permissions:
  contents: write
jobs:
  web-deploy:
      name:  Deploy
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
      - name:  Get latest code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        
      - name: Setup .NET Core SDK ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: dotnet restore
      - name: Build
        run: dotnet publish --configuration Release --no-restore

      - name:  Upload files via FTPS
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@v4.3.4
        with:
          server: my-real-domain.com
          username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
          local-dir: ./bin/Release/net6.0/publish/
          server-dir: ./
          protocol: ftps
          dangerous-clean-slate: true
          exclude: |
            .cspell.json
            package.json
            package-lock.json
````

Comment: Hi, don't you get a `File is being used by another process` error for your DLL, because the app pool keeps running?

Comment: @Pieterjan Yep I do. It sucks. I ended up not using github to deploy and instead I just use the "publish" feature inside Visual Studio. I also had [other issues with that FTP deploy action](https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action/issues/391) which occur even for purely static files, no .NET builds involved

Answer (score 0):

Basically 403 forbidden error message because that you haven't setup your default page correctly. Please kindly check it on your end first. If still not resolve your issue, you may refer to this post https://windowswebhostingreview.com/how-to-fix-403-forbidden-error-message/ about few things that you need to check.